# Can't find <sstream> directory

Tags: c++

Why can't my compiler find the directory?

```
#include <sstream>          // Provides std::ostringstream strDestXML;
```

The error is:

```
30  71  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include\graphics.h
[Error] sstream: No such file or directory
```

I use DevC++ with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Relase

I want to use the graphic library for my problem.

Comment: Search your system for a file with name "sstream".  For example, on my ubuntu system, it is at "/usr/include/c++/5/sstream".  (There is no extension for this c++ include.)  If you can not find it, perhaps it is not installed, or your tool suite failed to install.

Comment: Is TDM-GCC installed in the expected location, i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\`, or somewhere else? You may want to check that installation path.

Comment: How do you launch gcc, from the command line?

Comment: It isn't a directory.